# RODBCext syntax examples for parameterized select queries with a subquery

Tags: r, rodbc

I'm trying to find use RODBCext syntax for multiple parms in the same query with at least one of them part of an IN clause.

This is the approach I'm taking, but it doesn't like the IN part:

Error: unexpected symbol in "AND col2 "

This is how I'm specifying the parms:
prm <- data.frame( '2', c('B01', 'B12', 'B23', 'B34', 'B45'))

This is the SQL"
dataResult <- sqlExecute, connHandle, query = "
select col1, col2, col3
from tblA
where col1 = ?
and col2 IN ?
"
, prm 
, fetch = TRUE)
odbcClose(connHandle)

I've looked at [the CRAN pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/RODBCext.pdf)

and 
[the vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing the syntax to use OR rather than IN. This makes it harder to read, but the code runs successfully.